# <form method="post"> doesn't work in this <table>

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

The Post form inside this table class doesn't respond when submitting

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>NO.</th>
            <th>NAME.</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach($users as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->firstname}} {{$value->lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->phonenumber}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{-- <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{$value}}"> --}}
                        @if($value->status == 'Waiting')
                            <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="Waiting" class="label label-primary">Waiting</span></td>
                        @else
                            <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="Approved" class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </form>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

it works outside just under the table and I have no idea why it doesn't work, anyone has any ideas? I also tried using a link button instead but that too doesn't work.

Comment: That's invalid HTML. Place your whole table inside the form or place the form inside a `<td></td>`. Also, your `<button>`s should end with `</button>`, not with `</span>`

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "doesn't respond"? How is this related to PHP or even Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the form into the `<td>` tags. tr > form > td is invalid HTML.

```html
<tr>
    <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->firstname}} {{$value->lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->phonenumber}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
    <td>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                {{-- <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{$value}}"> --}}
                @if($value->status == 'Waiting')
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Waiting" class="label label-primary">Waiting</button>
                @else
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Approved" class="label label-success">Approved</button>
                @endif
            </div>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And your buttons are closed with `<span>` tags. Fixed that.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why do you think that it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakenly close your `button` element with `span`

```
                        @if($value->status == 'Waiting')
                            <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="Waiting" class="label label-primary">Waiting</button></td>
                        @else
                            <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="Approved" class="label label-success">Approved</button></td>
                        @endif
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the route method used on `{{ route('admin') }}`

The same code I tested by creating a controller on my end

```
Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
```

Blade entry

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>NO.</th>
        <th>NAME.</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($adverts as $value)
        <tr>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('test.store') }}">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$value->id}}">
                    <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="Approved" class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
                </div>
            </form>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

    </tbody></table>
```

My controller

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

NOTE : I pointed the form action to `action="{{ route('test.store') }}"`

I think the form action you have used is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think this code helps you.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>NO.</th>
            <th>NAME.</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach($users as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->firstname}} {{$value->lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->phonenumber}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
            <td>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{-- <input type="hidden" name="value" value="{{$value}}"> --}}
                        @if($value->status == 'Waiting')
                            <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="Waiting" class="label label-primary">Waiting</button></td>
                        @else
                            <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="Approved" class="label label-success">Approved</button></td>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```